# Determining point of intersection.

Tags: calculus

How can I determine the other point of  intersection of a tangent line that intersect the graph of the $f(x)= 2x^3+10x^2-28x$. I don't know where to start.

I did the first question which is determining the equation of the tangent line at $x=-3$. I got $y=-34x+18$ as the answer. Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation of the tangent line is correct.

To find the intersection points of two curves you need to set their equations equal and solve for $x$. So you need to solve

$$2x^3+10x^2-28x=-34x+18$$

Rearranging

$$2x^3 + 10x^2 + 6x - 18 = 0$$

> Keep in mind that you already know that $x=-3$ is a solution and not only that, it is a double zero, because the tangent line only touches the  graph.  So we factor out $(x+3)^2$ on the right hand side to see:
>  $$2x^3 + 10x^2 + 6x - 18= 2(x+3)^2(x-1)$$ 
>  So the tangent line intersects the graph at $x=1$.